# Filtering an unbound datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview, filtering

I have a datagridview which shows a full list of students and their year groups among other information.
I want to bea ble to filter this using a combobox so that I can choose for eg Year 9 and the datagridview will only show pupils and their details in year 9. 
All kind of help is appreciated - I am new to C#

I have tried the following code on my combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow df in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string TextVar;
            TextVar = comboBox1.Text;


            if (dataGridView1.Rows[df.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString()== (TextVar))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[df.Index].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[df.Index].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a bindingsource? If so, you may need to put your code between `bSource.SuspendBinding();` and `bSource.ResumeBinding();` in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Hi - thanks for reply, no it is unbound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
I realize you said it's unbound but please do try this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bc = BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
    bc.SuspendBinding();

    for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() == comboBox1.Text);
    }

    bc.ResumeBinding();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - i have put this is but I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" error appearing. Thank you so much for taking time to do this.

Comment: It looks like bc is null - obviously has something to do with the data source but I am not familiar with this.

Comment: @Edel_28 okay so remove the three lines that have "bc" on them and try again, and if that doesnt work try adding `dataGridView1.Refresh()` or `dataGridView1.Update()` at the end of the code

Comment: This does not throw up an error and seems to be trying to filter. However the datagrid is updated to show no results. Perhaps it is looking in the wrong column?

Comment: Cells{3} = 4th column, make sure its the correct one otherwise it may be causing to set all your rows to invisible

Comment: how do I check that Cells{3} is the 4th column? Is there a way?

Comment: It seems to be pointing to the correct column, yet no results appearing

Comment: Just place a breakpoint so the app pauses when it reaches that line of code, and verify that its comparing the right values

Comment: Just realised I was looking for "year 9" when i had them saved at "9". When i changed this your code worked. THANK YOU!!